# How to compare Object value

Tags: javascript

I'm new with JavaScript, I need little help. I have one solution to find object.gender(males) only, but I want to know if there is there another way to find object value 'males' only? Instead of having a counter, just to fetch males only.

```js
// Create Object
function Candidate(id, name, surname, gender, age, education, status){
    this.id = id,
    this.name = name,
    this.surname = surname,
    this.gender = gender,
    this.age = age,
    this.education = education,
    this.status = status
}

// Total Male Candidates
function maleCandidatesFunc(){
    let counter = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        statisticMale = data[i].gender;
        if(statisticMale == 'male'){
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
    }  
    maleCandidates.innerText = counter;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `reduce` with the accumulator being the number of males found so far:

```
maleCandidates.textContent = data.reduce((a, person) => a + (person.gender === 'male'), 0);
```

If you're not comfortable with `.reduce`, you can use `.filter` followed by checking the `.length` of the filtered array:

```
maleCandidates.textContent = data
  .filter(person => person.gender === 'male')
  .length;
```

If you want an array of just the female objects, use

```
data.filter(person => person.gender === 'female')
```

Comment: The first line of code, instead of the counter is giving 'false' value

Comment: Oops, need an extra set of parentheses for operator precedence

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Create Object
function Candidate(id, name, surname, gender, age, education, status){
    this.id = id,
    this.name = name,
    this.surname = surname,
    this.gender = gender,
    this.age = age,
    this.education = education,
    this.status = status
}



function maleCandidates(data){
  return data.reduce((acc, user) => acc + user.gender === "male", 0)
}

maleCandiates.innerText = maleCandidates(data)
```